# I want to take information from a google sheet cell and have it replace a part of a url that i'm pulling information from

Tags: google-sheets

=SUBSTITUTE(index(IMPORTHTML("https://finviz.com/quote.ashxt=AAPL","table",8),9,4),"*","")

I want to take G2 (the tkr cell) and insert the ticker to replace the AAPL in the url.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O4ew.png

Thank you if you can find a solution. I don't know how to articulate it well so if you need further clarification I can help.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://finviz.com/quote.ashxt="&G2, "table", 8), 9, 4), "*", )
```